# PCF8583 with Arduino delay of one second?

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c, atmega328, rtc

I'm trying to interface the RTC chip : PCF8583 with Arduino Uno. I'm using exactly the circuit shown below except instead of the variable capacitor near the crystal oscillator, I've used a 22pF ceramic capacitor.

[image]

For the programming side, I've used the [Arduino PCF8583 library](https://github.com/edebill/PCF8583)

The code I'm using is the following :

```
#include <Wire.h> // necessary, or the application won't build properly
#include <stdio.h>
#include <PCF8583.h>

/*
*  read/write serial interface to PCF8583 RTC via I2C interface
*
*  Arduino analog input 5 - I2C SCL (PCF8583 pin 6)
*  Arduino analog input 4 - I2C SDA (PCF8583 pin 5)
*
*  You can set the type by sending it YYMMddhhmmss;
*  the semicolon on the end tells it you're done...
*
*/

int correct_address = 0;
PCF8583 p (0xA0);   
void setup(void){
 Serial.begin(9600);
 Serial.print("booting...");
 Serial.println(" done");
}

void loop(void){
 if(Serial.available() > 0){
   p.year= (byte) ((Serial.read() - 48) *10 +  (Serial.read() - 48)) + 2000;
   p.month = (byte) ((Serial.read() - 48) *10 +  (Serial.read() - 48));
   p.day = (byte) ((Serial.read() - 48) *10 +  (Serial.read() - 48));
   p.hour  = (byte) ((Serial.read() - 48) *10 +  (Serial.read() - 48));
   p.minute = (byte) ((Serial.read() - 48) *10 +  (Serial.read() - 48));
   p.second = (byte) ((Serial.read() - 48) * 10 + (Serial.read() - 48)); 
   // Use of (byte) type casting and ascii math to achieve result.  

   if(Serial.read() == ';'){
     Serial.println("setting date");
     p.set_time();
   }
 }


 p.get_time();
 char time[50];
 sprintf(time, "%02d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d",
  p.year, p.month, p.day, p.hour, p.minute, p.second);
 Serial.println(time);
 delay(3000);
}
```

When setting the time and date, everything went ok, but when getting date/time the result is always HALF the period of the elapsed time, for example if I set the time 10:30 and I check it after 30 MINUTES, I get 10:45 instead of 11:00.

I really don't know if this is a hardware or software issue. If anybody has any idea about this issue, that would be highly appreciable !

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I'm sorry, but that serial reading code is awful. Read this: https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/01/reading-serial-on-the-arduino/

Comment: It seems to me the 3 V battery serves no useful purpose.

Comment: Shouldn't VCC (PCF8583 pin 8) be connected? Together with the diodes and battery backup?

Answer (score -1):

1. Check your schematic vs the datasheet and make sure that it makes sense.
2. Check to make sure that your input is right. You can print it back right away, or set the etc to a known good time and see if it keeps time.
3. Check the library to make sure that it is good.